# Filter pandas dataframe for first N unique values per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I need to filter a large dataset of variables with entries for multiple dates. In this instance I want to keep only data entered on the very first date.

For example in the dataset below:

```
dfex = pd.DataFrame({'names':['jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim',
                           'bob','bob','bob','bob','bob','bob',
                           'sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara'],
                  'dates':['01-01-19','01-01-19','01-01-19','01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19',
                           '01-05-19','01-05-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19',
                           '01-02-19','01-02-19','01-02-19','01-02-19','01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19']})

dfex['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(dfex['dates'])
dfex
```

jim would keep the first 3 rows, bob the first 2 and sara the first 5.

Comment: Can a date be repeated after a change? For instance if Jim's `01-06-19` was `01-01-19`, what should happen?

Comment: Great question! If not in order everything on that first date should still be kept.

Comment: OK then my first approach should work. Note that you can use `transform('min')` in place of `transform('first')` if what you really want is the oldest date.

Comment: Thanks! I notice that returns slightly different results in my actual dataset. What's the difference? Is first just first occurance?

Comment: Also, is it possible to enter a range. Say I wanted the first 5 unique dates for each individual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `N = 1` (original question) use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = dfex[dfex.groupby('names')['dates'].transform('first').eq(dfex['dates'])]
```

If the initial date can be repeated later on in the group and you don"t want to keep those further occurrences, use:

```
out = dfex[dfex.groupby('names')['dates']
           .transform(lambda s: s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
   names      dates
0    jim 2019-01-01
1    jim 2019-01-01
2    jim 2019-01-01
9    bob 2019-01-05
10   bob 2019-01-05
15  sara 2019-01-02
16  sara 2019-01-02
17  sara 2019-01-02
18  sara 2019-01-02
```

##### first `N` unique dates

Irrespective of their values (just by position)

```
N = 5
out = dfex[dfex.groupby('names')['dates']
           .transform(lambda s: pd. factorize(s)[0]<N)]
```

Or for the first `N` oldest date:

```
N = 5
out = dfex[dfex.groupby('names')['dates']
           .rank('dense').le(N)]
```

Output:

```
   names      dates
0    jim 2019-01-01
1    jim 2019-01-01
2    jim 2019-01-01
3    jim 2019-01-05
4    jim 2019-01-06
5    jim 2019-01-07
6    jim 2019-01-08
9    bob 2019-01-05
10   bob 2019-01-05
11   bob 2019-01-07
12   bob 2019-01-08
13   bob 2019-01-09
14   bob 2019-01-10
15  sara 2019-01-02
16  sara 2019-01-02
17  sara 2019-01-02
18  sara 2019-01-02
19  sara 2019-01-05
20  sara 2019-01-06
21  sara 2019-01-07
22  sara 2019-01-08
```

##### for the last `N` unique

```
N = 5
out = dfex[dfex[::-1].groupby('names')['dates']
           .transform(lambda s: pd. factorize(s)[0]<N)]
```

Or `N` newest dates:

```
N = 5
out = dfex[dfex.groupby('names')['dates']
           .rank('dense', ascending=False).le(N)]
```

Output:

```
   names      dates
4    jim 2019-01-06
5    jim 2019-01-07
6    jim 2019-01-08
7    jim 2019-01-09
8    jim 2019-01-10
9    bob 2019-01-05
10   bob 2019-01-05
11   bob 2019-01-07
12   bob 2019-01-08
13   bob 2019-01-09
14   bob 2019-01-10
20  sara 2019-01-06
21  sara 2019-01-07
22  sara 2019-01-08
23  sara 2019-01-09
24  sara 2019-01-10
```

Comment: Sorry, one last question... what if I wanted the last 5 dates?

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thanks! Hopefully some other poor soul out there can benefit too.